# Does the dual Banach space $B(\ell^\infty)$ have weak* normal structure?

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, fixed-point-theorems, banach-spaces, convexity, convex-geometry

Let $K$ be a bounded closed convex subset of a Banach space $E$. A point $x$ in $K$ is called a *diametral point* if 
$$
\sup_{y\in K} \|x-y\|={\rm diam}(K).
$$
where ${\rm diam}(K)$ denotes the diameter of $K$.
The set $K$ is said to have *normal structure* if every non-trivial (*i.e.* containing at least two points) convex subset $H$ of $K$ contains a non-diametral point of $H$.

A dual Banach space $E$ has *weak${}^*$ normal structure* if every non-trivial weak* compact convex subset of $E$ has normal structure.

> Does the dual space $B(\ell^\infty)$ of bounded linear operators on $\ell^\infty$ have weak* normal structure?

Recall that the natural predual of  $B(\ell^\infty)$ is the space $\ell^\infty\hat{\otimes}\ell^1$ where $\hat{\otimes}$ denotes the projective tensor product.

Comment: Could you give an example of a dual Banach space which does not have weakstar normal structure?

Comment: The set $\lbrace (x_n): \sum_n x_n=1, x_n\ge 0\rbrace$ in $\ell^1$, as a dual of $c$, is such an example.

Comment: Just observe that an affirmative answer would imply that every separable reflexive space has normal structure.